# Why Physics.OverlapCircle on instantiate object is not detecting any game object on a specific layer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I instantiate an object, and I need to detect if is overlapping with the player (on the layer 'player'). Before that, I've tried if it's working for normal (not instantiated) objects and it worked fine.

I tried to see what `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` is returning, and the value was always null.

That's my part of the code:

```
    void Update()
    {
        Checking_for_hit();
        Checking_for_collisions();
    }
    
    void Checking_for_hit()
    {
        if (time_s < 0f && ok)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("Die");
            ok = false;
        }
        else if (ok) 
            time_s -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        
        if( Physics2D.OverlapCircle(point.position, attack_range, playerlayer) && pm.isfighting)
        {
            ok = true;
            Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
            return;
        }
        
    }

    void Checking_for_collisions()
    {

        if ( Physics2D.OverlapCircle(point.position, radius, playerlayer) && time < 0f)  
        {
            if(is_waiting)
            {
                hp.TakeDamage_without_anim(15);
                time = CoolDownTime;
            }
            else if(pm.isfighting)
            {
                hp.TakeDamage_without_anim(15);
                time = CoolDownTime_moving;
            }
            else
            {
                hp.TakeDamage(15);
                time = CoolDownTime_moving;
            }
            
        }
        else 
            time -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are telling it to ignore `playerLayer`.

The layerMask parameter of `Physics.OverlapCircle(point, radius, layerMask)` sets the layer to ignore when performing collision detection.

Comment: Unity documentation says: **The optional layerMask allows the test to check only for objects on specific layers.** Go to [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html).

Comment: Yeah. And they mean that it excludes the layers that are masked.  The documentation is pretty poor at pointing that out.

Comment: Although as we are mm t shown the value of playerlayer this might be true. However it is a mask so it excludes that which is listed not includes them